# Clear multiple textbox using JavaScript on button click

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I working in `Asp.net c#`. I have a task to clear multiple `textbox` on `button click`, but now according to the requirement I have to use `JAVASCRIPT`. So I can't do that with `C#` code.
Now I am using the following :

**JAVASCRIPT** Function **:**

```
function clrCtrl() {
    document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = "";

}
```

with this method the line of is greater. Now when I have 20 30 of textbox this code is not efficient so plz give me any suggestion to this....

Comment: By textbox, are you referring to a text area or an input that is type text?

Comment: it is an asp.net textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give class name to the text box to which you want to clear then try to use

`document.getElementsByClassName("MyTestClass")` to get elements and use your logic to do whatever you want.

eg:-

```
function clrCtrl() {

    var elements = [] ;
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName("MyTestClass");

    for(var i=0; i<elements.length ; i++){
       elements[i].value = "" ;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using `JQUERY`? Jquery selectors has different combinations that may help you to more easily reset controls based on CSS classes, control types, using 'likes'.

http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/

Here is an example from jquery page:

```
<input class="myClass" name="man-news">
<input name="milkman">
<input name="letterman2">
<input name="newmilk">

<script>
     $( "input[name*='man']" ).val( "has man in it!" );
     $( ".myClass" ).val("setting value based on class")
</script>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use "dummy" CSS Class names against them and empty them that way... rather than "obfuscate" control IDs

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery you could add a style class like textbox to each of your textboxes and then do `$('.textbox').val('');`
you html would look something like
`<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox" CssClass="textbox" />` for each of you text boxes make sure to include `CssClass="textbox"`

Answer (score 0):

You should gather the input elements you want to clear first, and then just loop on them to erase their content :

```
function clrCtrl() {

    var elems = [] ;
    elems = elems.concat(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));
    elems = elems.concat(document.getElementsByTagName("textarea"));
    //and so on

    for(var i=0,c=elems.length ; i<c ; i++){
       elems[i].value = "" ;
    }

}
```

I would also advice to give a common className to those elements if you want to group them :

```
function clrCtrl(groupName) {

    var elems = [] ;
    elems = elems.concat(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));
    elems = elems.concat(document.getElementsByTagName("textarea"));

    for(var i=0,c=elems.length ; i<c ; i++){
       if(elems[i].className==groupName){elems[i].value = "" ;}
    }

}
```

Or if you are targetting only modern browsers, you can use the "getElementsByClassName" method :

```
function clrCtrl(groupName) {

    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(groupName) ;

    for(var i=0,c=elems.length ; i<c ; i++){
       elems[i].value = "" ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function funClear() {

    document.getElementById("form1").reset();

} 

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1">
Name:<input type="text" id="txt"><br><br>
Email:<input type="text" id="txt"><br><br>
Phone:<input type="text" id="txt"><br><br>
Message:<input type="textarea" height="50" width="70" id="txt"><br><br>

<input type="button" name="clear"value="clear" onclick="funClear()">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```